# Change cookies path in webapp2

Tags: python, google-app-engine, session-cookies, webapp2

I'm using webapp2 sessions lib on appengine. In my App the default path for cookies is `/`, but I want an special cookie to be valid only on `/api/.*`. The `set_cookie` method does not allow to specify the configuration for the new cookie, only the name and backend of the cookie. I also didn't find a way to change the path after creating the cookie.

```
from webapp2_extras import sessions


sessions_store = sessions.get_store(request=self.request)
special_cookie = sessions_store.get_session(name='special_cookie', backend='securecookie')

... # change ``special_cookie`` path ? how?
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You aren't using cookies, you're using session data. That's entirely different. Cookies are stored in the browser, sessions are stored in the server. Because the idea of a session is that it's side-wide, you'll have to manually implement whatever path-specific logic you have in mind.

If you want to use an actual cookie with a specific path, that's easy and [documented in the web2py docs](http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/04#Cookies):

```
response.cookies['mycookie'] = 'somevalue'
response.cookies['mycookie']['expires'] = 24 * 3600
response.cookies['mycookie']['path'] = '/'
```

**What's the difference between a session and a cookie?** A cookie is a single chunk of information *stored on the browser*. So for example, if you want to keep track of shopping cart contents, plus font size preference, you might store several cookies, like so:

- SHOPPING_CART: Item1,Item2,Item3
- FONT_SIZE: 12pt
- NAME: Fred

Each of those variables would be stored *in the browser* with cookies. With a session, you only store one piece of information in the browser, a session_id:

- SESSION_ID: 56a3y678

Then on the *server side*, you'll have a session database that might look like this:

```
| SESSION_ID | KEY           | VALUE
---------------------------------------------------
| 56a3y678   | shopping-cart | Item1,Item2,Item3
| 56a3y678   | font-size     | 12pt
| 56a3y678   | name          | Fred
```

Storing information like this server side has a number of advantages. For one, you can store more information than the browser might let you. Also, because the server maintains its own database, you can trust it more safely; while a cookie of is_admin_user could not be trusted, a session variable could, generally.

The downside, obviously, is that instead of relying on the browser to keep everything updated, you're relying on your server software. So for example, if you have 10 web servers and users rotate between them, they all must talk to the same session database in order to work right.

Comment: Thanks Ken! As I understand, sessions are somehow based on cookies, isn't it? I would prefer to stick with the sessions lib of webapp2. But if I do not find other way to achieve what i'm looking for, I would implement your idea, at least to create the cookie. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem. I updated my answer to explain the difference between session variables and cookies.

Comment: Thanks Ken! What I will do is: "devide" the app. Since appengine does not support SSL on custom domain, I will do Cross Site Request to https://<app-ip>.appspot.com (backend). I will transfer the namespace over a cookie to the backend. The frontend will only use a cookie with a boolean var wich indicate if the user is already authenticated with the backend. Since the namespace is only transmitted over a secure connection, there's not a big deal is the frontend cookie is captured by a snnifer. Also, the namespace is encrypted inside a securecookie, so the user can not change it.

Comment: Oh nice. For what it's worth, I had success running a GAE SSL site using Nginx as a proxy. Nginx serves the custom domain, and proxies the URL to App Engine's appspot domain. The downside is, of course, speed.

Answer (score 1):

By default [SessionStore](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2_extras/sessions.html#webapp2_extras.sessions.SessionStore) class is instantiated using [default configuration options](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2_extras/sessions.html#webapp2_extras.sessions.default_config), where `path` for `cookie_args` is set to `'/'`.

If you want your cookie to have a different path, e.g. `/api`, you will want to create your own instance of [SessionStore](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2_extras/sessions.html#webapp2_extras.sessions.SessionStore) class. It can be instantiated with overridden configuration values. This way you can have session store, which is valid only for specified path.

Comment: This idea came to my mind reading the ``sessions.py`` source. But I do not get how to pass my SessionStore subclass to ``get_store`` function. Will I need to re-implement this function too? :/